# I have too much data for MS Access. How can I use the data?

Tags: excel, ms-access

I have 4 different excel tables. If I import them all into Access I get an error, related to the 2 gigabyte maximum for Access.

I can import the 4 tables as linked tables. However I cannot open them all at once because again, I'll get the same error. I've tried creating a union query shown below, but again I get the same problem.

`Select * from table1 union all select * from table2 union all select * from table3 union all select * from table4;`

I'm really at a loss on what I can do. Basically, the 4 tables relate to quarterly sales data and I want to be able to create a pivot table based on the year (either in Excel or Access).

I can combine the 4 tables into 1 excel file, but when trying to create a pivot table I get an error saying there isn't enough RAM on my computer.

What are my options to view this data?

Comment: If you run Compact after importing each sheet, will all the data fit in Access?

Comment: @pnuts unfortunately this is for a business analyst who requested that I do this for her. I am just a lowly peon. If I cant figure it out I'll ask her to remove some columns, but preferably it would be better to have all the columns that she gave me in the file

Comment: No access to a bona fide database, huh? Then you could link tables to the database, which allows you to sidestep the file size limit.

Comment: Export to a Sql, or sqlite database? run the query from access or excel on that databse? Or run MSSQL Compact and use MS Report Builder? Basically stop using a client based database for a commercial level data structure. /if not possible is it an option to create compact forms of each seperate table (create 1 pivot based on 4 pivots?) basically a summary of each table that then gets summarized?

Comment: Do you really need to *realize* the full dataset, or do you really want to run aggregate functions for data analysis?

Comment: First of all, Excel doesn't have tables.  Excel is a spreadsheet, not a database.  This is what happens when people try to use Excel as a database.  Aside from that, how many columns are in it?!?  Access can handle a lot of data, much more than Excel's maximum number of rows.  I've packed several hundred thousand records into an Access table before it freaked out on me.  See if you can break the data out into smaller pieces with less columns.  I find it impossible to believe that quarterly sales data can be spread out across that many columns.

Answer (score 2):

SQL Express has a limit of 10GB (and it's free).  (from here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993(v=SQL.110).aspx )

If you store the data in SQL Express, you can query the data directly from Excel and forgo using MS Access.

Excel has a limit of # rows it can handle, but you can overcome that using the free PowerPivot add-in from Microsoft: http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/excel-help/power-pivot-add-in-HA101811050.aspx

hope that helps

Mike